# How can I make the mouse pointer leave a fullscreen application in a multi-monitor setup?

Tags: windows-vista, multiple-monitors, fullscreen

I'm often playing a fullscreen game (like Civilization or Anno) and watching a DVD on another monitor in the meantime.

But as soon as the game starts the mouse pointer seems to be trappend on the primary monitor and I have to Alt-Tab out to skip a scene for example.

Is there any way I can move the cursor onto the second monitor without leaving the game? Some configuration setting or a third-party software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Until now nobody provided a working answer, so I provide my own until I there's a better one.*

It seems that this is a limitation by the DirectX fullscreen mode. The only workaround I found was getting rid of the fullscren mode and play in **windowed mode**.

Answer (score 2):

[UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/other_features.asp) has a hotkey to move the mouse to the next monitor.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It looks like all the games I tested capture the cursor, exclusively.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Ctrl]-[Alt] ... I have no particular reason to expect that to work, but combinations like that (sometimes [Shift]-[[Alt] or other combinations, sometimes held down, other times pressed and released) have been used to "escape" from various VMware, VNC, and similar windows).